# Linked List implementation of FileSystem directories

Tags: java, linked-list, file-system

I am writing wrapper classes in Java which override methods of an existing implementation, in order to handle an edge case.  The full implementation is a bit more complex than needs to be posted here, so I've written a simplified class containing only the parts I'm requesting assistance on.

**Problem Summary**

I am extending two classes:

One class designed as an "enumeration" class, abstracting a directory on a filesystem which contains symbolic links to other directories.  (Real world: "/sys/block".). It has two methods, a `scan()` method to generate the list of (linked) subdirectories, and a `getFirst()` to return the first element of the list.

The second class is an "entry" class, abstracting the pointed-to directory enumerated by the first class.  It has two methods, a `getName()` method to return the directory's path as a string, and a `getNext()` method to iterate to the next element.

**Constraints**

- Compatibility with JDK 8 or earlier
- Single-threaded use may be assumed
- Constructors may be altered as required.
- Must implement (at least) the two specified classes and the two methods on each.

**Focus of review**

The `scan()` method is my struggle here. I think I may have overcomplicated the solution in two ways:

- The nested `try ... catch` blocks in the `scan()` method seem unusual.  Am I missing a simpler way to handle this?
- (UPDATE: Self-answered this second question, below.) The implemented pattern is obviously a singly linked list that I'm working around by passing around an `ArrayList` implementation.  I can imagine the `DirEntry` class containing only its `Path` and a `DirEntry next` object, but attempts to generate such a list seem even more complex or less performant than the workaround I've created.

````
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.FileSystems;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class DeviceList {

    /**
     * Class representing a parent directory which contains symbolic links to other
     * directories
     */
    static class DirEnumerator {

        private Path dirPath;
        private List<DirEntry> entryList = Collections.emptyList();

        public DirEnumerator(String path) {
            dirPath = FileSystems.getDefault().getPath(path);
        }

        /**
         * Scans the directory for entries
         *
         * @return The number of entries found
         */
        public int scan() {
            try (Stream<Path> paths = Files.walk(dirPath)) {
                List<Path> linkedDirs = paths.filter(Files::isSymbolicLink).map(p -> {
                    try {
                        return Files.readSymbolicLink(p);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        return p;
                    }
                }).collect(Collectors.toList());
                this.entryList = new ArrayList<>();
                for (int i = 0; i < linkedDirs.size(); i++) {
                    this.entryList.add(new DirEntry(entryList, linkedDirs.get(i), i));
                }
                return this.entryList.size();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                this.entryList = Collections.emptyList();
                return 0;
            }
        }

        /**
         * Gets the first entry in the scanned list
         *
         * @return The first entry if it exists; null otherwise
         */
        public DirEntry getFirst() {
            return entryList.isEmpty() ? null : entryList.get(0);
        }

    }

    /**
     * Class representing a directory
     */
    static class DirEntry {
        private List<DirEntry> entryList;
        private Path path;
        private int index;

        public DirEntry(List<DirEntry> entryList, Path path, int i) {
            this.entryList = entryList;
            this.path = path;
            this.index = i;
        }

        /**
         * Gets the path name of the directory entry
         *
         * @return a string representing the path
         */
        public String getName() {
            return this.path.toString();
        }

        /**
         * Gets the next entry in the list
         *
         * @return the next entry if it exists; null otherwise
         */
        public DirEntry getNext() {
            int nextIndex = index + 1;
            return nextIndex < entryList.size() ? entryList.get(nextIndex) : null;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Test on any directory containing symbolic links to other directories
        DirEnumerator de = new DirEnumerator("/sys/block");
        int n = de.scan();
        System.out.println("Found " + n + " directories.");

        DirEntry e = de.getFirst();
        while (e != null) {
            System.out.println("Directory: " + e.getName());
            e = e.getNext();
        }
    }
}
```
````

Comment: It seems like the getNext method should be a method of the Enumeration class, not the Entry class.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc I agree, but unfortunately those are the constraints I'm working under for the class I'm extending.  I think I did figure out a way to do that list portion and may self-answer the second question momentarily.  First question still valid.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are overkilling your task. Consider the following:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.FileSystems;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class DirectoryEnumerator {

    private final Path rootPath;
    private final List<Path> paths = new ArrayList<>();
    
    public DirectoryEnumerator(String path) {
        this.rootPath = FileSystems.getDefault().getPath(path);
    }
    
    public int scan() throws IOException {
        try (Stream<Path> pathStream = Files.walk(rootPath)) {
            List<Path> linkedPaths = pathStream.map(p -> {
                try {
                    return Files.readSymbolicLink(p);
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    return p;
                }
            }).collect(Collectors.toList());
            
            linkedPaths.forEach(path -> {
                paths.add(path); 
            });
            
            return paths.size();
        } 
    }
    
    public List<Path> getTraversedPaths() {
        return Collections.unmodifiableList(paths);
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DirectoryEnumerator de =
                new DirectoryEnumerator(
                        "C:\\Users\\username\\Documents");
        
        try {
            System.out.println("Scanned: " + de.scan());
            de.getTraversedPaths().forEach(System.out::println);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            throw new RuntimeException(ex);
        }
    }
}
```

Essentially, all you do is providing a class with two methods:

1. scanning the directory tree starting from some root directory,
2. obtain the list of the `Path` objects as the result of the 1. method.

Questions? Leave me a message, and I will see what I can do.

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out a simpler way to do the second question, building the Linked List by iterating backwards from the generated paths.

````
    static class DirEnumerator {

        private Path dirPath;
        private DirEntry first = null;

        // ...

        public int scan() {
            try (Stream<Path> paths = Files.walk(dirPath)) {
                List<Path> linkedDirs = paths.filter(Files::isSymbolicLink).map(p -> {
                    try {
                        return Files.readSymbolicLink(p);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        return p;
                    }
                }).collect(Collectors.toList());
                this.first = null;
                int i = linkedDirs.size();
                while (i-- > 0) {
                    this.first = new DirEntry(linkedDirs.get(i), first);
                }
                return linkedDirs.size();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                this.first = null;
                return 0;
            }
        }

        // ...
    }

    static class DirEntry {
        private Path path;
        private DirEntry next;

        public DirEntry(Path path, DirEntry next) {
            this.path = path;
            this.next = next;
        }

       // ...
    }
```
````